# CSV to SQL SERVER hosted on AppHarbor

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, appharbor

I have a CSV file which I wish to populate into a SQL Server table hosted on AppHarbor.

I am currently connected to the SQL Server Database via SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

---

I am traditionally from a mySQL background. And in PHPmyadmin, I am able to click a button to import a CSV file into a new table, then simply rename the table within php myadmin.

---

Is there any similar functionality in SQL Server?

How can I insert table data from a CSV file hosted on my local machine, onto a SQL server table hosted in AppHarbor?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but can the utility will help DTSWizard.exe

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import wizard.

In SQL Server Management Studio:

1. Right click the database
2. Select Tasks
3. Select Import Data...
4. Use wizard to import the file

This will support data movement to / from many different data formats (excel,csv,flat,sql server...)